# onKeyLongPress проблемы

Tags: android

Вообщем мне нужно отловить длинное нажатие на кнопки громкости. Делаю так.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    event.startTracking();
    return true;
}

@Override 
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) { 
    return true;
 }

public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode,KeyEvent event){
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN){
        //Do your stuff here
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Вниз", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show();

        return true;
    }
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP){
        //Do your stuff here
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Вверх", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); toast.show();

        return true;
    }
    return onKeyLongPress(keyCode,event);
}
```

Событие `onKeyLongPress` работает, но не работают системное изменение громкости, если методы `onKeyUp` и `onKeyDown`  возвращают `false`, тогда громкость работает, а `onKeyLongPress` нет. В чем дело? Кто знает?

Comment: `return onKeyLongPress(keyCode,event);` - наверное хотели `return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode,event);`?

Comment: Можно и супер, это ничего не меняет

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется возвращение return onKeyLongPress() не нужно здесь. Попробуйте возвратить false.

Возможно [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7985901/4752492) поможет:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) {
       event.startTracking();
       return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Попробовал, все так же. Мне кажется что дело в  onKeyDown и onKeyUp если они возвращают true, их нужно переопределить, что бы они что то делали

Comment: Я добавил возможное решение, попробуйте.

Comment: Нет. Не получается. Либо true, тогда работает onKeyLongPress, либо false, тогда работаюет изменение громкости го не работает onKeyLongPress